# Replace for-loop with updateOne with a bulk operation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I fetch multiple APIs and merge them into one array of JSON-objects and once this is done I want to insert the new documents that exists in my array but not in the DB, and if they already exits I want to update them so the DB always has the most recent data. Below is the code I'm using right now but I think this causes problems when closing the connection since when the cron-job is running the connections is only growing.

```
client.connect(function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    const collection = client.db("my_db").collection("my_collection");

    for (const index in foo) {
        const bar = foo[index];
        collection.updateOne(
          { uid: bar.uid },
          { $set: bar },
          { upsert: true }
        );
    }
    client.close();
});
```

How can I replace the for-loop with one MongoDB operation that does the same?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this code below:

```js
client.connect(async function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  const collection = client.db("my_db").collection("my_collection");

  const queryBulk = [];

  for (const index in foo) {
      const bar = foo[index];
      const queryUpdate = collection.updateOne(
        { uid: bar.uid },
        { $set: bar },
        { upsert: true }
      );
      queryBulk.push(queryUpdate);
  }

  const results = Promise.all(queryBulk);
  // update results  
  console.log(await results);

  client.close();
});
```

**Update:** Or if you wan to still using `bulk`, then you can use this code below:

```js
client.connect(async function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  const collection = client.db("my_db").collection("my_collection");

  var bulk = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

  for (const index in foo) {
      const bar = foo[index];
      bulk.find({ uid: bar.uid }).updateOne({ $set: bar });
  }

  bulk.execute((err, result => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  }))

  client.close();
});
```

I hope it can help you.